# how to insert a javascript value into a sql database this is a microsoft database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database

hi i am tryign to create a store locator and i want to put the users latitude and longitude up into the data base how would i do this i am using javascript to get the results and im going to use php for the database this is the code i am using to get the users location

```
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}



function showPosition1(position) {
var locations = [
    ['store1', -2.063150, 2.516503, 4],
    ['store2', -2.064824, 52.518436, 5],
    ['store3', -2.068214, 52.519898, 3],
    ['store4', -2.068558, 52.512769, 2],
    ['store5', -2.070875, 52.510758, 1]
];




lon1 = position.coords.longitude * 0.0174532925;
lat1 = position.coords.latitude * 0.0174532925;
i = 0;

while (i < locations.length) {
    function round(x) {
        return Math.round(x * 10) / 10;
    }
   x.innerHTML += "<br>Distance " + round(calcDist(lon1, lat1, locations[i][1] * 0.0174532925, locations[i][2] * 0.0174532925));
    i++;

}
```

}

all my code is working i just want to be able to put the lon 1 and lat1 into my database any ideas would be much appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: just submit the val via form or ajax to a php file which handle the request and insert it in your dbms

Comment: the problem with that is the value is not input by the user and im not familiar with ajax coding so i wouldnt know where to start

Comment: the value is found using geolocation so my javascript runs the funtion but the user doesnt have to put anything into a form

Comment: ... but you can put the val via JS to a form, hidden field, or just call an ajax submit or what ever

Comment: could you show me some code how to do this because i have never used the hidden field before how would i link this to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create another page that does your database insert.
Assuming you are using IIS - you write a page in C# or VB that reads the Request.QueryString["latitude"] & Request.QueryString["longitude"].
From there you can use standard .net code to update the SQL Server.

To send the data from browser to server:
On the client side (javascript) you would use the jQuery ajax method to call that page passing your data.
e.g.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'url_to_server_page.aspx'
    , data: 'latitude=90&longitude90'})
    , success: function (data) { alert('data'); }
});
```

If you're not using ASP then only your language would change but the basic struture of how you send data to the server is the same - client page sending data to server page.
This ajax example uses a default GET for simplicity but since you are updating a database you should do this as a POST.

Comment: this has worked thanks it took me a little bit of time to get it to work how i wanted it cause i have never used ajax before thanks