# does this code do what i need it to do

Tags: c#, api, geolocation

Hi I am trying to create a store locator and I am trying to get the user to input their    location manually and then convert that into latitude and longitude without use of googles API due to the restrictions of it T&C and I have come across this piece of code will this do what I need it to do and if it doesn't is there a way I can use this to get what I want. 
This code is c# and and i got it from this link http://code.google.com/p/geocoding-net/

```
    IGeoCoder geoCoder = new GoogleGeoCoder("my-api-key");
    Address[] addresses = geoCoder.GeoCode("123 Main St");
```

The reasons why I ask is because I don't have much experience within C# I just need someone to maybe point me in the right direction I just a little help from someone to you need to look into this or an example to work off I don't mind learning new code I'm just not sure what I'm looking for to get this to work.

Comment: ... errr why dont you try?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code doesn't do what I needed it to do because you still need to use someones API which is not what I wanted but it does work if you use googles API or someone elses API. im just wondering if anybody knows how to do this manually using javascript or c# or ajax without having to use an api to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your 2 previous questions[**1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049652/how-to-insert-a-javascript-value-into-a-sql-database-this-is-a-microsoft-databas)and [**2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088998/get-latitude-longitude-from-address-without-googles-geolocation) you have PHP available. This means you will probably have MySQL available as well.

You can use the zipcode/postcode of the user along with a database of these codes. These databases are available for most contries either free or for a fee.